# what are the possible ways of setting up antivirus for azure linux virtual machine and how?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, azure-rm-template

My question is "how to set up antivirus for Linux virtual machine in azure".There are  many websites which shows ways for setting up antivirus for  windows virtual machine in azure but I want it for Linux.

Comment: If you want to protect your Linux VM, [Azure Security Center and Azure Virtual Machines with Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/security-center-linux-virtual-machine) is a good choice. If you want to install other software, I suggest the [Azure VM Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/features-linux).

Comment: Thank u got an idea.

Answer (score 0):

can check this links: if u want to install inside of the OS u can access VM Extensions or otherwise use security center

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-antimalware

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/security-center-linux-virtual-machine

Comment: Linux is not supported by  Antimalware, please read carefully again.

Comment: I did not meant that Linux will support Anitmalware. For better understanding, i have given.